# DataTable column - Filter by selectItems itemLabel?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I've tried researching this and work arounds, so I've reached the point of asking:

```
<p:column headerText="ProjectStatusCode" filter=?? filterMatchMode=?? >
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{person.statusCodeIDForProject}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="None" 
                      itemvalue= "-1"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.allStatusCodes}" 
                       var="c" 
                       itemLabel="#{c.statusCodeName}" 
                       itemValue="#{c.statusCodeID}"/>
        <p:ajax listener="#{backingBean.editStatusCodeForProject(person.personID, person.statusCodeIDForProject)}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu> 
</p:column>
```

Ideally, I want to filter the column by the itemLabel (which in this case is the statusName). The status name has more value to the front end user than an ID.

**Edit**

This is primefaces 3.5.8

Comment: Use a lazyDataModel and you have all control

Answer (score 0):

Try this

the facelets page:

```
        <p:dataTable var="bb" value="#{backingBean.dataList}" widgetVar="dataTable"
                     emptyMessage="No item found with given criteria">
            <p:column filterBy="#{bb.status}" headerText="list header" footerText="exact" filterMatchMode="exact">
                <f:facet name="filter">
                    <h:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()" >
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.statusList}"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{bb.status}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

the trick here is to let your `StatusCode` class `toString()` return `just` `statusName` as so

```
public class StatusClass {

    String statusName;
    int statusCode;

    public StatusClass() {
    }

    StatusClass(String name, int i) {
        this.statusName = name;
        this.statusCode = i;
    }

    public String getStatusName() {
        return statusName;
    }

    public void setStatusName(String statusName) {
        this.statusName = statusName;
    }

    public int getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(int statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }


    //return just the status name
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + statusName;
    }

}
```

and in your BackingBean your

```
private ArrayList<DataClass> dataList;//points to your dataTable value
private ArrayList<StatusClass> statusList;//points to your statusList for selectOneMenu
```

i hope this helped